# SQL Server 2012 Invalid Column in Referenced Table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, create-table

I am trying to create these 3 tables in a database:

```
CREATE TABLE MEETS(
Date            date,
Opponent        char(100),
Result          char(100),
JUScore         int,
OpponentScore   int
CONSTRAINT      MEET_PK PRIMARY KEY(Date, Opponent)
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE ROSTER(
PlayerID        int         PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
PlayerLastName  char(100),
PlayerFirstName char(100),
Position        char(100),
Hometown        char(100),
HighSchool      char(100),
Class           char(100)
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE PLAYERS(
Date            date        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MEETS(MEET_PK),
Opponent        char(100)   FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MEETS(MEET_PK),
PlayerName      char(100),
CONSTRAINT      PLAYER_PK   PRIMARY KEY(Date, Opponent)
```

);

The first two tables were created just fine, but I'm getting an error with the PLAYERS table saying:Foreign key 'FK__PLAYERS__Date__52593CB8' references invalid column 'MEET_PK' in referenced table 'MEETS'. The column in the MEETS table seems to already be there, so I'm not sure how I could write it so that it displays correctly. Does a constraint not count as a column? If so, what is another way to write it?

Comment: What you want to do is put a foreign key on both columns, I assume. e.g. `CREATE TABLE PLAYERS ([Date] DATE, Opponent CHAR(100), FOREIGN KEY FK_blah ([Date], Opponent) REFERENCES MEETS([Date], Opponent), PRIMARY KEY ([Date], Opponent));`. EDIT: To be clear, a foreign key references columns, not a constraint itself.

Comment: That doesn't look to be something I can do since it gives me a syntax error. I probably should've mentioned that I'm using SQL Server and not MYSQL.

Comment: er... Yeah, change, `FOREIGN KEY FK_blah` to `CONSTRAINT FK_Blah FOREIGN KEY`. Alternatively, if you don't care about your FK's name, just `FOREIGN KEY ([Date], Opponent) REFERENCES MEETS([Date], Opponent)` works.